# When does WhatsApp show that someone on the other end is Typing?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

WhatsApp has two status options shown under the name of the person in chats, namely *Online* and *Typing*.

I understand that the *Online* option is shown if the person is on WhatsApp at that moment.

But, what does the *Typing* mean? Does it mean that the person is **replying specifically to me**, or replying to me **or someone else**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to admit this is an interesting question considering a variety of responses raised [here](https://www.quora.com/When-does-WhatsApp-show-is-typing):

Personally the version that deem to be more accurate is

> The text *“typing…”* appears specifically  under the **name of the
>   person sending you a message** when that person **starts typing a
>   message to you**

The exact instance at which it appears raises debates, but from several chat applications I've used (currently Disa), the occurence is when the **keyboard appears and occasionally vanishes if no key is tapped after a few seconds**.

To support this sometimes when the chat window goes out of focus, and then reopened the *typing  status* reappears when the keyboard pops up again (with or without key press)

Comment: the exact instance when "typing..." shows can best be answered by WhatsApp developer team. But I agree with assumption that the when keyboard appears on sender's device is good trigger to inform other side that user is typing

Comment: Agreed! @AADAndroidEnthusiasts